# Zend framework https request

Tags: php, zend-framework, https, protocols

I'm trying to make a https request using zend framework 1.11, with http everithing is working fine, but when i change the request url to https://etc.com, I'm not more able to get the response.

i'm trying like a was reading in the manual like that:

```
$uri='https://url.com';

$adapter = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl();
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $client->setUri($uri);
    $client->setMethod('POST');
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);
    $adapter->setConfig(array(
            'curloptions' => array(
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)
    ));

    Log::notice("URL: " . $uri);
    $response = $client->setRawData($xml, 'application/xml')->request('POST');
```

i activated already in my php.ini the php_curl.dll.

So only with https is not working, maybe somebody can tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Likely invalid certificate. If you can't change the server certificate to valid one, you have to set curl option to ignore invalid certificate:

```
$addapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: It's the same, i have configure the adapter with setConfig(), thank anyway